# Software for projecting the PC screen to an android/iphone without intermediate services

Tags: software, tools

I'm giving  a class next semester in a room with no preinstalled projector system and next to non-existent wifi accessibility (during the busy hours its not possible to connect to the router; let alone stream video or images).

It's a class (in engineering statics) that I want to give examples of how to use and incorporate software in the solution of exercises. I find it more beneficial when I show them examples from my computer screen.

Solutions I have considered are:

- use the university teleconferencing software (based on BigBlueButton) to share my screen (however the wifi bandwidth is the limiting factor).
- get a mobile projector: the setup, and swithing on/off lights every time I am making the presentation seems to me disproportionate to the amount of time I am expecting to use it.

So I was wondering: if someone knows of a system that uses Bluetooth (or similar technologies)(maybe also wifi, but through the local router) to project simultaneously (and securely) to about 20-40 smartphone screens.

Hopefully, this will not be considered off-topic. (I lean anyways towards the projector, so this is not crucial, however I am interested if someone has a solution that has tried because it seems that the technology exists to do it for one, and I would imagine it might be feasible for many).

Comment: I would suggest asking this on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I can try to elaborate if this direction makes sense, but I think you can stream your desktop to a local web server using VLC. Then you can open a local hotspot, so the rest of the group  would be able to connect to you and open your stream in their browsers. Thus, no app would be needed on their side.

Comment: @rg_software actually it would make sense, and I would appreciate it if you would.

Comment: @user2390246 I can appreciate your perspective , and thanks for the recommendation. Still, unless the question is closed here, because I'd value the input of people who tried it in a classroom environment (not a generic audience) I'll wait a little bit.

Comment: There are orthogonal solutions to the basic problem. Send a url to a page with the images the day before the lecture. This allows previews by students.

Comment: @buffy which I agree that's a perfectly acceptable solution, it is not in line with my approach. I favor impromptu sessions lead by Q&A with the students. I find that involving the audience enhances the interaction and keeps the students more alert that rigid pdfs. Also, it helps them to see how they can debug problems which can occur (probably this is as important if not more so)

Comment: Do students want to try to follow along engineering diagrams on their tiny phone screens? Just host class on Zoom for a day

Answer (score 3):

It turned out to be more complex than I expected, as most of the setups I tried actually failed. However, this one seems to work.

1. Get [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com). Skip initial setup, in the main window find "Sources" box and add a "Display capture" source. This will add a desktop picture to your stream. Next, go to Tools, Settings, Advanced, Recording pane, and set "Filename Formatting" to some wildcard-free name like `playlist`. Go to Output, set Output Mode to "Advanced", go to Recording tab, set Type to "Custom Output (FFmpeg)", FFMpeg Output Type to "Output to File" and in the "File path or URL" box below set a path to any empty folder on your disk, e.g., `C:\temp`. Set "Container Format" to `hls`. You can also set "Keyframe interval" to something lower like 90 to reduce latency (more details [here](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/how-to-do-hls-streaming-in-obs-open-broadcast-studio.945/)). Close the settings.
2. Now if you press "Start recording" (*not* "Start streaming"), your session will begin. It generates a lot of garbage in the temp folder, so you'll need to clean it afterwards. By this moment we have a screencast running, so the next task is to share it. The trouble is that the `hls` format we use isn't supported natively everywhere, so we need to create a helper HTML page.
3. In the same temp folder create a page `index.html`. Copy & paste there this ["quick example page"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41014197/how-can-i-play-a-m3u8-file-video-using-the-html5-video-element/48688707#48688707). If you want to operate in a full offline mode, download [`hls.js`](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@latest) file and change the link to it in your `index.html`. Oh, also it makes sense to change `controls` into `autoplay` in the `video` tag there.
4. Finally, run a web server from your temp folder: `python -m http.server`. If you are in the same local network with your audience, just give them the link to your screencast: `http://<your-IP>:8000/`